# Add Group title to three-level XSLT grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

The following XSLT does everything I need to group my XML data by degree and then by Electives and Requirements. But I can't get the `<ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>` title to appear only once per section. I need a parent grouping outside of the degree with only one `<ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>` data element to introduce it.

Here is the XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="STX049 Catalog parsed.xml" -->
 <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:key name="degrees-by-title" match="Section" use="ICCB1" />

 <xsl:template match="/*">
 <CrystalReport>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Group/Group/Group"/>
 </CrystalReport>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Group">
 <xsl:text>
 </xsl:text><Degree><areaofstudy><xsl:value-of select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" /></areaofstudy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Details/Section[generate-id() = generate-id(key('degrees-by-title', ICCB1)[1])]" mode="group">
 <xsl:sort select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
 </xsl:apply-templates>
 </Degree>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Section" mode="group">
 <department><Degreetitle><xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGDEGREE1" /></Degreetitle>
 <Certtitle><xsl:apply-templates select="CCD11" /></Certtitle><xsl:text>
 </xsl:text><DegreeDesc><xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGCOMMENTS1" /></DegreeDesc><xsl:text>
 ICCB Code </xsl:text><ICCBcode><xsl:apply-templates select="ICCB1" /></ICCBcode><xsl:text> | Field of Study Code: </xsl:text><ProgramID><xsl:apply-templates select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" /></ProgramID>
 <xsl:variable name="courses" select="key('degrees-by-title', ICCB1)" />

 <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
 <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'N']" />
 <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Requirements'" />
 </xsl:call-template>

 <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
 <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'Y']" />
 <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Electives'" />
 </xsl:call-template>
 </department>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="CourseGroup">
 <xsl:param name="courses" />
 <xsl:param name="title" />

 <xsl:if test="$courses"><xsl:text>
 </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$title" />
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$courses">
 <xsl:sort select="FlagElectives1" order="ascending" />
 <xsl:sort select="DEPARTMENT11" />
 <xsl:sort select="CRSNO1" />
 </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Section"><xsl:text>
 </xsl:text><Details><class><deptname><xsl:apply-templates select="DEPARTMENT11" /></deptname><xsl:text>    </xsl:text><courseno><xsl:apply-templates select="CRSNO1" /></courseno><xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
 <classname><xsl:apply-templates select="CRSTITLE1" /></classname><xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
 <classcredit><xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" /></classcredit></class></Details>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ACPGDEGREE1/text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' DEGREE')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CCD11/text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' CERTIFICATE')" />
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the basic XML Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CrystalReport>
 <Group Level="1">
  <Group Level="2">
  <Group Level="3">
    <Details>
      <Section>
        <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
        <CCD11/>
        <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
        <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
        <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
        <CRSNO1>1110</CRSNO1>
        <ACRBPRINTEDSPEC1/>
        <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
        <CRSMINCRED1>2</CRSMINCRED1>
        <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
        <CRSTITLE1>Using Computers: An Introduction</CRSTITLE1>
        <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
        <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
        <ACRBLABEL1>CIS REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
        <CRSMAXCRED1/>
        <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
      </Section>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <Section>
        <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
        <CCD11/>
        <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
        <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
        <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
        <CRSNO1>1150</CRSNO1>
        <ACRBPRINTEDSPEC1/>
        <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
        <CRSMINCRED1>3</CRSMINCRED1>
        <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
        <CRSTITLE1>Intro to Computer</CRSTITLE1>
        <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
        <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
        <ACRBLABEL1>CIS</ACRBLABEL1>
        <CRSMAXCRED1/>
        <FlagElectives1>Y</FlagElectives1>
      </Section>
    </Details>
  </Group>
  </Group>
 </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

To produce the following XML:

```
<CrystalReport>
 <Degrees><areaofstudy>Accounting</areaofstudy)
 <Degree>
<department>
  <Degreetitle>AAS DEGREE</Degreetitle>
  <Certtitle />
  <DegreeDesc>The Accounting program</DegreeDesc>
  <ICCBcode>3203</ICCBcode>
  <ProgramID>ACCOU.AAS</ProgramID>
  <h1>Program Requirements</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1150</courseno>
      <classname>Intro to Computer</classname>
      <classcredit>3</classcredit>
      <Elective>Y</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
  <h1>Program Electives</h1>
  <Details>
    <class>
      <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
      <courseno>1110</courseno>
      <classname>Using Computers: An Introduction</classname>
      <classcredit>2</classcredit>
      <Elective>N</Elective>
    </class>
  </Details>
 </department>
</Degree>
</Degrees>
</CrystalReport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="STX049 Catalog parsed.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:variable name="allSections"
                select="/CrystalReport/Group/Group/Group/Details/Section" />

  <xsl:key name="kArea" match="Section" use="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1"/>
  <xsl:key name="kDepartment" match="Section"
           use="concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ICCB1)" />

  <xsl:variable name="deptFirsts"
             select="$allSections[generate-id() = 
               generate-id(key('kDepartment',
                concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ICCB1))[1])]" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CrystalReport>
      <Degrees>
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="$allSections[generate-id() = 
                 generate-id(key('kArea', ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1)[1])]"
          mode="group"/>
      </Degrees>
    </CrystalReport>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="area" select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" />
    <areaofstudy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$area"/>
    </areaofstudy>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <Degree>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$deptFirsts[ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 = $area]"
                           mode="department">
        <xsl:sort select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Degree>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="department">
    <department>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="departmentValues" />

      <xsl:variable name="courses"
              select="key('kDepartment', 
                   concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ICCB1))" />

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'N']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Requirements'" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'Y']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Electives'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </department>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="departmentValues">
    <Degreetitle>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGDEGREE1" />
    </Degreetitle>
    <Certtitle>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CCD11" />
    </Certtitle>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <DegreeDesc>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGCOMMENTS1" />
    </DegreeDesc>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;ICCB Code</xsl:text>
    <ICCBcode>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ICCB1" />
    </ICCBcode>
    <xsl:text> | Field of Study Code: </xsl:text>
    <ProgramID>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
    </ProgramID>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CourseGroup">
    <xsl:param name="courses" />
    <xsl:param name="title" />

    <xsl:if test="$courses">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$courses">
        <xsl:sort select="FlagElectives1" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="DEPARTMENT11" />
        <xsl:sort select="CRSNO1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <Details>
      <class>
        <deptname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="DEPARTMENT11" />
        </deptname>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <courseno>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSNO1" />
        </courseno>
        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
        <classname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSTITLE1" />
        </classname>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
        <classcredit>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" />
        </classcredit>
      </class>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ACPGDEGREE1/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' DEGREE')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CCD11/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' CERTIFICATE')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, this produces:

```
<CrystalReport>
  <Degrees>
    <areaofstudy>Accounting</areaofstudy>
    <Degree>
      <department>
        <Degreetitle>AAS DEGREE</Degreetitle><Certtitle />
        <DegreeDesc>The Accounting program</DegreeDesc>
        ICCB Code<ICCBcode>3203</ICCBcode> | Field of Study Code: <ProgramID>ACCOU.AAS</ProgramID>
        Program Requirements
        <Details>
          <class>
            <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
            <courseno>1110</courseno>
            <classname>Using Computers: An Introduction</classname>
            <classcredit>2</classcredit>
          </class>
        </Details>
        Program Electives
        <Details>
          <class>
            <deptname>ACCOU</deptname>
            <courseno>1150</courseno>
            <classname>Intro to Computer</classname>
            <classcredit>3</classcredit>
          </class>
        </Details>
      </department>
    </Degree>
  </Degrees>
</CrystalReport>
```

Comment: After running this through Dreamweaver + Safari and Oxygen, I am getting only the <areaofstudy> titles and no other data, such as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CrystalReport><Degrees><areaofstudy>Accounting</areaofstudy><areaofstudy>Liberal Arts</areaofstudy><areaofstudy>Heating, A/C &amp; Refrigeration</areaofstudy>...

Comment: I looked through the code to see if I had any bad line breaks or broken elements and didn't find any. But I just reran the transformation and it seems to work now in Dreamweaver/Safari combo. In Oxygen, I keep getting memory errors. Any idea why?

Comment: One note, this XSLT seems to be much more memory intensive than the other versions you suggested.

Comment: I see.  Could be due to the use of 3 keys if you have a very large input document, though I can't think of an alternate approach at the moment.

Comment: There is a huge error in this XSLT. It is recreating ALL the level 2 data for each Level 1 title. It's putting a complete copy of all the courses under each title. That's probably why it's taking so long to generate and giving the memory out errors in Oxygen.

Comment: Alright, well would you please provide an example input that demonstrates this flaw (and show what the output should look like)? It's difficult to verify three levels of grouping with only two sample items.

Comment: I posted some sample data at Pastebin at http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=h5MPRMzE Let me know if this is enough data.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I've made some improvements.  Could you give it a try?  You haven't specified what fields should be used to group each level. Currently I'm using `ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1` for the top level, `ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1+ACPGDEGREE1` for the second level, and `ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1+ACPGDEGREE1+ICCB1` for the third level, but I notice that a lot of the data has blank values for `ACPGDEGREE1`, so there's a good chance it's still not right. Could you clarify that?

Comment: The three levels should be 1) ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 2) ICCB1 (Degrees or Certificates) 3) FlagElectives1 (y or n).

You can't use ACPGDEGREES1 because that only appears for Degrees, Certificates uses the element CCD11.

Comment: I have tested the new XSLT and it seems to be working fine as is. It runs so much faster now that it's not looping through all the data 28 times. Kudos. No more crashes or memory out errors. I will check the data and make sure it is all there.

Comment: Based on your recent description of the three levels, I think I had one degree of grouping too many (I was grouping on ACPGDEGREE1 as the second degree and this was producing multiple `<Degree>`s per area of study.  There should be only one `<Degree>` per `<areaofstudy>` right? I've updated my solution, which simplifies it a small bit.